# Как дублировать imageView?

Tags: java, android, java-ee, android-sdk, activity

Как дублировать imageView?

Есть картинка с разными цветами
[image: asd]

Как дублировать картинку? Если растянуть, то там не картинка будет, а ужас какой-то. Есть ли такой метод в XML у ImageView или что-то подобное? Это все используется в адаптере для listView. Что можете предложить?

Comment: Я ничего не понял, если честно )

Comment: Такой же принцип как в текструой. берем кусок 2 на 2 и размазываем по всему контейнеру imageVIew, допустим размер ImageView 100 на 100, закидываешь в ImageView картинку 2 на 2 включаешь какой нибудь метод или атрибут, указываешь размер ImageView и весь этот маленький кусок продублируется столько сколько нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен правильно ли я понял, но

backrepeat.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/back" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

---

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat">

</ImageView>
```

Comment: @АбдулаХакерДроин, ага

Comment: Ну я короче вручную уже сделал, сидел подсчитывал размер и рисовал короче))), а оказывается можно просто атрибут указать ахахаах. Прикольно, надо запомнить).

Comment: @АбдулаХакерДроин аккаунты плодить не надоело? )